# Why Google Maps Places only returns to me the name of the place with this type of code (e.g.: V83X+9G) in getDetails method?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working in a project which requires all the information about a specific place. The information that I get is not complete and I got it in the following  format: "V83X+9G" e not "V83X+9G Paris, France". The code that I'm using to get this information is the following:

```
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var service2 = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.textSearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

           placeId5 = results[0].place_id;
          var request1 = {
            placeId: placeId5,
            fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry']
          };

          service2.getDetails(request1, function(place, status) {
            var n = place.name.indexOf(" ");
            var new_place_name = place.name.slice(n+1,place.name.length);
            // placeName4 = new_place_name;
            placeName4 = place.name;
            var select = document.getElementById("location");
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = n;
            opt.innerHTML = place.name;
            select.appendChild(opt);
            var url = window.location.href;
    var n3 = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    var lastTwo = url.substring(n3 + 1);
            var g = new XMLHttpRequest();
            g.open("GET", "/insertCircle?raio=" + iCircle2.getRadius()/1000 + "&latitude=" + iCircle2.getCenter().lat() + "&longitude=" + iCircle2.getCenter().lng() + "&area=" + (Math.round((Math.PI * (iCircle2.getRadius()/1000) * (iCircle2.getRadius()/1000))*1000)/1000) + "&localizacao=" + new_place_name + "&place_id=" + placeId5 + "&mapa_id=" + lastTwo, true);
            g.send();
          });
        }
});
```

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?  I suspect the issue is that you aren't requesting the `formatted_address` field (or the `address_components` field, which might also contain that information).

Comment: You were spot on @geocodezip!

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `formatted_address` field in the Places Details request to get the full address of a place. Like this:

```
var request1 = {
    placeId: placeId5,
    fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry', 'formatted_address']
};
```

Then retrieve it in the response as follows:

```
service2.getDetails(request1, function(place, status) {
    var fullAddress = place.formatted_address;
    ...
});
```

Alternatively you may use `address_components`. Check out this link to see the full list of supported [Place Data Fields](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields). And there's a live working example of Places Details that displays the place's full address [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details).

Hope this helps!